# ng-click not working in google map angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i have two stores in database and am trying to get stores in google map marker is pointing that two stores.i have ng-click in that info window to pass id here ng-click is not working is there any idea to pass id through ng-click

```js
.controller('MapCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',
 
function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $http.get('****').success(function (data, dealers, response) {
        function initialize() {
            var serverData = data;
            $scope.locations = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
                var modal = [
                data[i].Store_Name, data[i].S_Location.Latitude, data[i].S_Location.Longitude, i, 'images/arrow.svg', data[i].S_Address];
                $scope.locations.push(modal); 
            }
            console.log($scope.locations);
            //---------------------------------------------------------
            //console i am getting like this
            var locations = [
                ['nokia store', '12.971599', '77.594563', '1', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a78953815356700bee698f'],
                ['samsung store', '12.9065534', '77.5774802', '2', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a786d1815356700bee6982'], ];
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 13,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {
                //console.log($scope.locations[i][1]);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locations[i][1], $scope.locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: $scope.locations[i][4],
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div class="marker-box"><div class="marker-title">' + $scope.locations[i][0] + '</div><input type="button" value="Book Now" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + $scope.locations[i][5] + ') "/></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
            $scope.map = map;
        }
        $scope.getid(id) {
            console.log(id);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that the plain HTML you are sending to the infowindow has not been passed through the Angular compiler, so it hasn't applied any magic to ng-click.

What you have to do is inject Angular's $compile service into your controller (which you should really be doing this stuff in a directive seeing that it is manipulating the DOM) and before you set the content of the infowindow, do something like this:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div class="marker-box"><div class="marker-title">' + $scope.locations[i][0] + '</div><input type="button" value="Book Now" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + $scope.locations[i][5] + ') "/></div>');
$compile(infowindow.content)($scope);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Try that and see if it works, it should, but if it doesn't make sure you are passing the right data into the $compile service. You may have to compile the HTML string *before* you call `infowindow.setContent()`

Good luck! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

**Update:**

Make sure that you inject the $compile service into your controller like so:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$compile',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, $compile) {
        ...
        // now you can use $compile
        $compile(infowindow.content)($scope);
        ...
    }
]);
```

Comment: i am new to angular  have not used angular directive can you please help me how can i write direct

Comment: It is one of the more advanced bits of Angular, but still not very difficult. Too much too teach here though, so I will refer you to [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals)

Comment: You don't need it to be in a directive for it to work, that is just a best practice of Angular. Try to get it working the way you have it now before you start considering creating a directive with it.

Comment: i have added but i am getting  $compile not added error help me out to move forward thanks

Comment: Make sure you are injecting the $compile service into your controller, see update above.